# QlikView diagram with relations between DB tables and QV objects

Tags: qlikview

May be anybody know.
Can I see via QlikView (something same to TableViewer) diagram with relations between my table in Db and QV objects (I mean tables which created in QlikView from qvd files).

Answer (score 3):

You can display the table structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to see how your tables are connected.

[image]

HTH